# Replace package import in a module

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, monkeypatching

I use a module that imports a function as a package import using relative import dot notation:

```
from .utils import target_func

class ClassINeed:

    def function_i_call(self):
        return target_func()
```

I want to import ClassINeed with `from classineed import ClassINeed` but replace `target_func` with a function of my own. Problem is, target_func is not part of the class I am importing. Therefore I do not see a way to access it. What would be a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On top of `from classineed import ClassINeed`, also do a `import classineed` then override the `target_func` as needed via `classineed.target_func = lambda : 'hello!'` for example.

P.S. Referring to the class `ClassINeed` with `classineed.ClassINeed` might be cleaner if you already have `import classineed`.

Comment: Does not work for me. This replaces the function in my import but not in the module itself. The original function is still being called when I instantiate ```ClassINeed``` and call ```function_i_need```

Comment: Hmm, weird that it worked for me then. Could you maybe find the module in `sys.modules` and override there? Also isn't subclassing `ClassINeed` better here?

Comment: I tried to override in sys.modules. But that does not work since the function is imported as relative dotted import.

Comment: I want to subclass ClassINeed but I stil need to replace ```target_func```

Comment: A probably ugly way of doing it might be through `unittest.mock.patch` like `with patch('package.classineed.target_func', new=lambda:123123): ...`
Also I just realised IPython does some magic that made me think it worked whereas just plain old Python does not, so apologies for that.

Comment: It would have probably been much easier to do it if you want to monkeypatch a whole module, but just one function is probably a tad bit messy.

Comment: Eventually it worked as proposed, problem was that I was importing the module as a whole and not the file where I wanted to replace the function. But it works as fomulated in the answer.